# Chat shows global SE reputation instead of site rep

Tags: support, chat

Why does the chat on SE site display the global reputation instead of the site reputation? From my account on [Christianity.SE](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/users/729/atheist) (which has around 200 points)

[image]

???

Comment: Christianity.SE scares me.

Comment: This is the kind of conversation that the assholes next to me at the bar are always having.

Comment: This is likely going to get closed as [meta-tag:status-declined] as this is intentional behavior.  All chat stuff is network-wide, including chat suspensions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

status-by-design, essentially; simply: that is how we chose to orchestrate reputation on chat.SE. It seemed logical:

- chat.SE spans most of the SE sites
- the reputation *as a barrier* is only intended to act at basic block of spam and throwaway abuse accounts - there aren't many rep-related facets to chat
- we're all for cross-site community discussions; we wouldn't want you unable to talk in different rooms
- if you *are* an invested SE user, we're happy to display that

Note that ♦ moderator status *is* tracked on a per-site basis.

Comment: But most mod powers on chat are universal, except for seeing hidden chat rooms.

Comment: I would expect rep to be displayed globally in (default) rooms and site-specific in site-specific rooms (which rep is used for deciding what privileges you have can be global all the time)